# recursive function to join accounts with at least one common user in PHP

Tags: php, function, recursion

I need a recursive function to group accounts based on user groups already in the same group.

But :

If grp1 => ['a', 'b'] and grp2 => ['b', 'c']
Here b make the link with grp1 and grp2
If I have another grp248 => ['a' , 'z'], as a is present in grp1 a link exist for grp1 grp2 and grp248 even if group2 has nothing in common with group248.

make chains like this person knows this person who knows this person etc ...

```
//input
$data = [
    'account1_id' => ['user1_id', 'user2_id'],
    'account2_id' => ['user2_id', 'user8_id'],
    'account4_id' => ['user15_id', 'user16_id'],
    'account5_id' => ['user15_id', 'user16_id'],
    'account7_id' => ['user24_id', 'user25_id', 'user26_id', 'user27_id'],
    'account8_id' => ['user29_id', 'user30_id', 'user8_id'],
    ];

//ouput need
$data = [
    0 => ['account1_id', 'account2_id', 'account8_id'],
    1 => ['account4_id', 'account5_id'],
    2 => ['account7_id'],
];
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what you mean by "join accounts with at least one common user"? In your output index 0, why are accounts 1,2 and 8 linked? Have you attempted solving this already? If so, post what you have even if you know it isn't doing what you want it to.

Comment: 1, 2 and 8 are linked because account1_id and account2_id have both user2_id. Account8_id is chained at this new group with user8_id present in account8_id and account2_id. Yes I have try solve this of course.. Many days. But I can't do it for the moment.

Comment: I added more explanations in main post

Comment: I see you posted some code that generates your expected output. Do you still need assistance? If not, move your code to an answer and you can mark it as solved.

Comment: Ok it's done. 24h for validate now. Ty for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find it :

```
$usersArray = array();
#first reverse array with user as key
foreach ($data as $idAcc => $users) {
    foreach ($users as $idUser) {
        if (!key_exists($idUser, $usersArray)) {
            $usersArray[$idUser] = array($idAcc);
        } elseif (!in_array($idAcc, $usersArray[$idUser])) {
            $usersArray[$idUser][] = $idAcc;
        }
    }
}

# make reduction
$newData = array();
foreach ($usersArray as $idUSer => $accountsId) {
    foreach ($accountsId as $accountId) {
        $addAsNew=true;
        foreach ($newData as $index => $accountsTab) {
            if (in_array($accountId, $accountsTab)) {
                $addAsNew=false;
                $newData[$index]=array_unique(array_merge($newData[$index],$accountsId));
                break ;
            }
        }
        if($addAsNew){
            $newData[]=$accountsId;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($newData);
```